# Doctrine2: Adding existing entity to parent, duplicates the parent

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, cascade

I have two related classes (OneToMany):

```
<?php
class Container {
    /**
     * @var Content[]
     * @\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\OneToMany(targetEntity="Content", mappedBy="contents", cascade={"remove"})
     */
    protected $contents;
}

class Content {
    /**
     * @var Container
     * @\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Container", inversedBy="contents", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    public $container;
}
```

Now when I add a new Content item the Container will be duplicated in database and the new Content item links to the duplicate.

I use the id of the parent Container, like this:

```
<?php
$newContent->container = $repository->find($passedIdOfContainer);

// ...

$em->persist($newContent);
$em->flush();
```

So basically I am just getting the existing entity record from database (which works), and set the attribute of my new content object with the existing object. But now the parent (Container) will be duplicated.

When I remove `cascade={"persist"}` I get the following error:

> A new entity was found through the relationship 'Content#Container'
>   that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity:
>   Container@0000...

What do I need to do, to create new child, with reference to parent, without duplicating the parent in database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Container
{
    /**
     * @var object
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *      targetEntity="Content",
     *      mappedBy="container",
     *      cascade={"persist", "remove"}
     * )
     */
    protected $contents;
}

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Content
{
    /**
     * @var object
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(
     *      targetEntity="Container",
     *      inversedBy="contents"
     * )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(
     *      name="container_id",
     *      referencedColumnName="id",
     *      onDelete="CASCADE",
     *      nullable=false
     * )
     */
    protected $container;
}
```

Assuming that you have all the methods set in your `Container` entity file so:

```
//......
$container->addContents($contentObject);

$em->persist($container);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: Am I not able to set the parent Container in content instead of adding the contents to parent?

Comment: Why do you need to such thing when there is this simple and common way of handling what you're trying to achieve? What's your business case?

Comment: I've tried to change the way of persisting the relation, as you recommended. Now at least, the parent is not duplicated. The JoinColumn seems to have no effect. The DB structure is identically. But when I persist the container the "container_id" column is NULL. When I set `nullable=false` I get an sql error, that NULL is not allowed. I've added the contents with `$container->addContent($content);` And in this method I call `$this->contents->add($content)`. $this->contents is filled with `new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection()` in constructor. Why stays container_id empty?

Comment: I think you have different problems so I cannot really help without having hands on. You probably refactor for code.

Comment: Well adding the content to the container creates a new record in content table. Just the relation is not persisted.

Comment: Make sure you have `public function __construct()
    {
        $this->contents = new ArrayCollection();
    }` in `Container`.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the gist! That helped! Now it works, thanks to this example: https://gist.github.com/tournasdim/cec9877b2cf9599571f9#file-examples-php-L20